# Does the developer payload persist when RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS is called in Google in-app billing?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

We are trying to find a way to identify specific purchases when using Google in-app billing via Google Play—specifically, to identify a specific purchased product on a new device, or after a memory wipe.  I've considered trying to retrieve the Google ID used in purchase, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792571/get-the-google-id-used-in-an-in-app-billing-purchase/9792626#9792626), but it's proven problematic.

However, the developer payload might provide a solution, but this depends on how it behaves.  Basically what I am hoping is that, when a purchase is restored using `RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS`, the developer payload put into the original purchase request is returned.  If so we can use this payload to identify a user: when they install the application on a new device, we restore transactions, and get the developer payload to identify them; otherwise we assume they are a new user and generate a new developer payload.

Can this work?  Does the developer payload persist for managed products?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a late reply :) 
I just tried in-app billing, and i can confirm you that the developer payload is returned also with RESTORE_TRANSACTION command.

I think your solution should work. Hope this late reply help you.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer.