# Get the Google ID used to download the application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, account, accountmanager

How can i find out which google account downloaded the application?

This question is related to [Get the Google ID used in an in-app billing purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792571/get-the-google-id-used-in-an-in-app-billing-purchase)

Thank you!

Comment: A phone can have multiple google accounts... There is always 1 default but nevertheless it can have multiple. Not an option to ask the user?

Comment: @Warpzit How do you know the default account in Android 3.2 and newer? Ask to user is not an option :S

Comment: Hey @JonathanNaguin ,Did you find any way to achieve this?If yes ,please share.If not you can share a workaround.Getting primary email address and asking user will not work in my case.
So if there is another solution to it , you can share.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best answer can be found here: [How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)
This might not be exacly what you want, but without asking the user, I think this is the closest you can get.