# Get in-app billing user account details

Tags: android, billing, in-app

I'm creating an Android application that implements subscriptions to digital content on my backend server. What I wish to do is obtain the name and email associated with the Play account that made the purchase, namely the same information I can get if I go to my Merchant account and view an order.

Using the TrivialDrive in-app billing example, I'm able to access the INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA and send that information to my backend server as the "Checking Subscription Documentation" recommends: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/billing_subscriptions.html

The documentation lists a typical implementation workflow and says:

> When the user successfully purchases a new subscription, your app
>   notifies a backend server, which stores the purchase token, user name,
>   and other information in a secure location.

Although I can store the purchase token, and other INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA how do I obtain the user name or email for that matter. From what I can piece togehter I suspect the account details like user name, email, subscripion expiration date must be requested from my back end server. It seems using the purchase token on my backend server is the key to accessing order information, but at this point I haven't found any clear way to go about doing this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I also can't figure out how to find out user info

Comment: @sberezin, have you solved your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the Google ID used in an in-app billing purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792571/get-the-google-id-used-in-an-in-app-billing-purchase)